# react-table v8 how to get options value for custom filter components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

How can i get `preFilteredRow` value to be use as options in my custom dropdown component. I've been struggle to display custom component but now im stuck again to get the value of selected column, right now im still doing it manually to populate the select `<option>`, here's my implementation as of right now:

Declaring the filter component

```
declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
  interface ColumnMeta<TData extends unknown, TValue> {
    filterComponent: (props: any) => any;
  }
}
```

column helper

```
const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor('attributes.category.data.attributes.name', {
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
    header: 'Categori',
    meta: {
      filterComponent(setFilterValue) {
        return (
          <select
            name="Category"
            aria-label="Category"
            className="block w-full rounded-lg border-gray-200 text-sm shadow focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-75"
            onChange={(e) => setFilterValue(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="MANUAL1">Manual Option 1</option>
            <option value="MANUAL2">Manual Option 2</option>
          </select>
        );
      },
    },
  }),
]
```

as you can see above, im still populating the select `<option>` manually to match the selected cell data and it worked fine. but i need to populate the `<option>` from the selected cell data. Anyone could enlighten me? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass any arguments to filterComponent(setFilterValue) function instead of setFilterValue, you can pass for example { column, table } in place where you call your 'filterComponent'